# How to pass column values one by one to a SQL function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

This is my table "LoadData"

| Sequence_Code | ID | Current_Year | Record_Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17AA | 310001 | 2017 | 2017-01-01 | S |
| 18AB | 310002 | 2018 | 2018-02-22 | A |
| 19AC | 310003 | 2019 | 2019-02-10 | S |
| NULL | 310004 | 2019 | 2019-02-20 | A |
| NULL | 310005 | 2020 | 2019-03-20 | A |
| NULL | 310006 | 2020 | 2019-04-20 | A |

How can we pass one by one 'ID' of only those records `where Sequence_Code is NULL` and Status is A, to the function?

My function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextSequenceCode_TEST] 
    (@LastSeqAlphabet varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN 
    -- will generate and update a sequence code in the same table
END
```

Please update the input parameters of the fFunction, if required.

Comment: You can't really do this.  You need to do it row by row, for instance, in a `select`.

Comment: Do you even need a function for this? What are your expected results here? Also, a function can't perform an `UPDATE` statement, so it won't be able to update said table.

Comment: Maybe you need CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY. What is the requirement? and the original query / table?

Comment: @Larnu I agree that the function will not update, I meant that My function is generating the value,which i am able to update in the table ,. my concern is for multiple ID's, that how can we pass Multiple ID's having status='A' and Sequence_Code IS NULL, one by one to the function,So it keep on generating the value and update statement will update it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff .. yes.. we need to do row by row..That's why i have written that if required please Change the parameter, bcoz i need to generate Sequence_Cd for ID's having status 'A' .

Comment: @Alin with a cursor?

Comment: What does `@LastSeqAlphabet` represent in your function? Is it even necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am over-simplifying this as I do not understand your request fully, but could this be as simple as:

```
UPDATE LoadData
SET
    Sequence_Code = dbo.GetNextSequenceCode_TEST ( ID )
FROM LoadData AS ld
WHERE
    ld.Sequence_Code IS NULL
    AND ld.[Status] = 'A';
```